# how to replace a value for string if letters are missing?

Tags: sql, oracle

I ran into a problem where i have to create a 'LettersOfName' column. As name suggest I have to get letter 2,3 and 5 from ORGANISATIONNAME column and letters 2 and 3 from CLIENTLASTNAME column, then concatenate to form letters of name column. The condition is if letters of name is not equal to length 5 than replace with '22222' also if any of the letters is missing from first name and last name than replace with '22222'. I am using this query.

```
select 


    ( CASE  WHEN LENGTH (UPPER( SUBSTR(ORGANISATIONNAME, 2,2) || SUBSTR(ORGANISATIONNAME,5,1)) || UPPER(SUBSTR(CLIENTLASTNAME,2,2))) != '5' THEN '22222' 
            ELSE UPPER( SUBSTR(ORGANISATIONNAME, 2,2) || SUBSTR(ORGANISATIONNAME,5,1)) || UPPER(SUBSTR(CLIENTLASTNAME,2,2)) END)
            AS LETTERSOFNAME


from client;
```

So, far this query runs fine, but when we have name like 'Jo Anne' or 'J Shark' it is missing letter '2' and '3' but does not replace the string with '22222'. When length is not equal to 5 it replaces with '22222'. I am using Oracle 12c.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would be quite helpful.

Answer (score 2):

If after the concatenations of the letters you remove all the spaces and the length of the remaining string is less than 5 then replace with `'22222'`:

```
SELECT
  CASE 
    WHEN LENGTH(REPLACE(SUBSTR(ORGANISATIONNAME, 2, 2) || SUBSTR(ORGANISATIONNAME, 5, 1) || SUBSTR(CLIENTLASTNAME, 2, 2), ' ', '')) < 5 THEN '22222'
    ELSE UPPER(SUBSTR(ORGANISATIONNAME, 2, 2) || SUBSTR(ORGANISATIONNAME, 5, 1) || SUBSTR(CLIENTLASTNAME, 2, 2))
  END LETTERSOFNAME 
FROM client
```

Or with a CTE:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT
    UPPER(REPLACE(
      SUBSTR(ORGANISATIONNAME, 2, 2) || 
      SUBSTR(ORGANISATIONNAME, 5, 1) || 
      SUBSTR(CLIENTLASTNAME, 2, 2), 
      ' ', 
      ''
    )) LETTERSOFNAME 
  FROM client    
)
SELECT
  CASE 
    WHEN LENGTH(LETTERSOFNAME) < 5 THEN '22222'
    ELSE LETTERSOFNAME
  END LETTERSOFNAME 
FROM cte
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=451e36b685840c59becb97b5add76b27).

Comment: This makes sense, will it work if client last name also have the same scenario? what if we use trim before substring?

Comment: Trim before substring would remove spaces from the left and right of the column. Do yo need it? Is there a case that the values inserted contain spaces at the start and at the end? About *the same scenario* for client last name I don't know what you mean.

Comment: I dont think i have a case where values contains spaces at start and at the end spaces are in between the names....the above logic is applied for one column only and not the second column?

Comment: The logic is you described it: *letters 2,3 and 5 from ORGANISATIONNAME letters 2 and 3 from CLIENTLASTNAME*. This is why there are 3 substring() calls in the code.

Comment: what if we want to replace only a '2' with missing letter?

Comment: I misunderstood the requirement - the condition is to replace 2 where missing letter and if length of string is not equal to 5 than replace '22222'.

Comment: If you have a new requirement then you should post a new question where you explain what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You should first remove the white space between the string and and then apply your `case` statement on it

```
replace ('J Shark', ' ', '')
```

Reason is white space is being counted as a character in `J Shark` and that is why second and third characters are missing.

Here is an example [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=dafdc9a44dbc65415cd4332b0b2320fd).

Answer (score 0):

Here is my approach:

1. Put both columns ORGANISATIONNAME and CLIENTLASTNAME to another table with identity column (to identify each row)
2. Write a function to split text by a string (in this case pass a space)
3. Get the identity and the splitted data to 2 tables each for column 1 and 2
4. Consider each table and apply your logic
5. Concatenate the row values separated by space, with the ID (1 record per ID)
6. Join the 2 tables (by IDs)

Join the 2 tables for matches in Col-Split data, and get the IDs
Now Query for the data in table in above 1

Comment: Well ... yes, if someone had to do it *manually*, but highly inefficient otherwise. A single query can do that (see e.g. @forpas' answer).

Comment: @Littlefoot, yes the answer of forpas is way better. Mine also can be done with a set of queries (then it is not manual) - I couldn't write it as my Oracle skills (specially split) are not that great). All which I wrote can be combined as a single query. It may not be as efficient.  Again thanks for pointing out this.